# TeX package not installing in R version 3.1.0

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I am trying to generate a pdf from .Rnw file using knitr package.
Please find the output of `sessioninfo()` below

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.5 formatR_0.10   stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.0
```

I have installed knitr but am unable to compile the code in the .Rnw file.
There is a popup that is saying "No TeX installation detected. Please install TeX before compiling". However both TeX and pdfLaTeX is not installing for this version of R, a warning message comes saying that TeX or pdfLaTex is not available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TeX installation is independent from R and cannot be installed via `install.packages`. Use e.g. [Miktex](http://miktex.org/) for Windows or [TexLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) for linux.

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer instead? I think it's a good answer to a valid question, which other people might also have.

Comment: @tonytonov: Thanks the issue is resolved. I installed Miktex separately and restarted my machine.

Answer (score 5):

As a convenience, the `installr` R package is a very convenient way to install TeX--and a bunch of other useful stuff. Just run `installr::installr()` and pick MikTeX (at least). (Not sure if it works for non-Windows.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Very neat package, never knew it existed.

Comment: It is indeed for Windows only.

Comment: @Gregor 
I'm having the same problem. I tried to use installr::installr(MikTeX) but it didn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping my comment into an answer. `knitr` uses `pdflatex` to generate a pdf. `pdflatex` is a part of TeX/LaTeX installation, which is not an R package and cannot be installed using R terminal (at least natively, because `installr` can actually do this, as indicated by @Gregor).

You need TeX installation on your machine to work properly with `knitr`. There are several options, with [Miktex](http://miktex.org/) for Windows or [TexLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) for linux.

Take a look at the [minimal example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) shipped with `knitr`. It starts with `\documentclass{article}`, which is a typical first line of a TeX file.

As a final note, [R markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) can produce HTML using `pandoc` instead, so it does not require TeX and may be a good alternative if you prefer not to use TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: The TexLive pkg is nearly 3GB. Thats quite large just to make PDFs out of rStudio (Notebooks to PDF). Is there any other way? @tonytonov

Comment: @michaelsinner See https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html : tarball is 3.3 mb.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Download and Install MiKTeX from http://miktex.org/2.9/setup

Step 2: Run

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

in R studio This command returns the path where Rstudio is trying to find pdflatex.exe In windows (64-bit) it should return C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe If pdflatex.exe is not located in this location Rstudio gives this error code 41.

Step 3: To set this path variable run:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/",sep=";"))
```